# How to connect to Google My Business API using OAuth protocol?

Tags: php, api, google-api-client, google-my-business-api

I am quite new to the use of Google APIs in PHP, and I am currently trying to get a list of the last Google Reviews submitted for a business.

At first, I used Google Places API to get the job done, which was simple to use (no need for OAuth connection process, a simple HTTP request was enough) but I've learned that this method only returns the last 5 reviews of a business, and I need to get a list of all the reviews.

That's why I red that I needed to go with Google My Business API if I wanted get the full list of reviews for a business.
But it's been days that I am trying to get this API to work, and I still haven't managed to even connect my app to the API using OAuth protocol.

Though I've started from a pre-made Github example, I'm still getting this error message when trying to acess the API : [PHP error message that I'm currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LrPH.png)

I don't understand why, as I really did everything that is mentionned in the documentation.

If anybody can have a little look at my code and help me knowing what is wrong with it, that'd be huge help really ! Any piece of information would be much appreciated.

Here is my code :

```
$credentials = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/allia-google-api/google-my-business-secrets.json';

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($credentials);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage");
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$my_business_account = new Google_Service_MyBusinessAccountManagement($client);

$list_accounts_response = $my_business_account->accounts->listAccounts();
var_dump($list_accounts_response);
```

Comment: Have you tried the 
OAuth 2.0 Playground yet? https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#make-simple-http-request

Comment: No I haven't, I am going to check this out, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

From the error I can see you have Authentication error, make sure your client_secrets which should be a json file is correct.
The following code is listing all the accounts and it is using the new Api named **Account Management API**.
Google My Business Api will get deprecated soon.

```
<?php 

include_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$credentials = __DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json';

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($credentials);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage");
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$my_business_account = new Google_Service_MyBusinessAccountManagement($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { // logout: destroy token
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
  die('Logged out.');
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) { // get auth code, get the token and store it in session
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}


if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) { // get token and configure client
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) { // auth call 
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header("Location: ".$authUrl);
    die;
}

$list_accounts_response = $my_business_account->accounts->listAccounts();
Var_dump($list_accounts_response);

?>
```

check here [https://github.com/google/google-my-business-samples/tree/master/php]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, and yes my credentials json file is correct. I just don't know what the $_GET['code'] is supposed to refer to. Any idea ?